# Can CGContextClipToMask mask all non-transparent pixels with alpha=1?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is it possible to make `CGContextClipToMask` ignore the grayscale values of the mask image and work as if it was plain black and white?

I have a grayscale image, and when I use it as a mask gray color are interpreted as an alpha channel. This is fine except for a point where I need to completely mask those pixels that are not transparent.

Short example:

```
UIImage *mask = [self prepareMaskImage];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mask.size, NO, mask.scale); {
  // Custom code
  CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), mask.size, mask.CGImage);
  // Custom code
}
```

Is it possible to adapt this code to achieve my goal?

Long story short: I need to make a transparent grayscale image become transparent where it originally was and completely black where it's solid-colored.

Comment: I am not sure I got you correctly. You do have a grayscale image without alpha (8bit, black/white channel only) and you want everything that was white to become 100% transparent and everything else shall become solid colored? What color? Or all grey values shall become 0% transparent without a color? You just have one channel of information... what shall happen with those information?

Comment: Grayscale with alpha channel -> All black image with alpha channel. Every pixel should become black, and should inherit the alpha channel from the main image.

Comment: By the way, in my case I only have images with alpha channel 0 or 1, no intermediate values. I just would like to convert all the gray pixel into black ones.

Comment: Okay, so the transformation is the following:
Black/White (aka grey) channel: Old: grey values -> New: all pixels black, Alpha channel: Old: empty/don't care -> New: 100% transparency where it was black in grey channel, 0% transparency otherwise. Correct?

Comment: Alpha channel: New: keep alpha channel values.

Comment: Still don't get it... keep alpha and make everything else black? That's all? In that case my solution will still work, but is a bit overachieving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem!  [Here's code](https://bitbucket.org/GeekAndDad/uiimage-stencil-experiment/overview) that does what I think you want in a simple sample project.  Similar to above but handles scale properly.  Also has option to retain the alpha in the mask image if you want.  Quick hacked together test that seems to work.

Comment: The `* self.scale` calls are doubling the images when I try the code. By the way, it seems to work pretty good.

Comment: huh. must not have tested it enough, sorry. Did you just remove that to get it working right?

Comment: Hey so you should grab the updated code.  Turns out the *self.scale is necessary but we have to run it back out through an UIImage which has the scale and dimensions in points.  Removing the *self.scale was making a mask at non-retina resolution and the edges were chunky as a result.  Works better now!  Thanks very much for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, I removed it, and got a fairly good result. I just released the app, but will include your code update in the next version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My rough idea would be the following:

1. You convert your input image to readable byte data in grey + alpha format. Maybe you have to do RGBA instead due to iOS limitations.
2. You iterate over the byte data modifying the values in place.

To simplify access, use a

```
typedef struct RGBA {
    UInt8 red;
    UInt8 green;
    UInt8 blue;
    UInt8 alpha;
} RGBA;
```

Let's assume `image` your input mask.

```
// First step, using RGBA (because I know it works and does not harm, just writes/consumes twice the amount of memory)
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSInteger rawWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSInteger rawHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
NSInteger rawBitsPerComponent = 8;
NSInteger rawBytesPerPixel = 4;
NSInteger rawBytesPerRow = rawBytesPerPixel * rawWidth;
CGRect rawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rawWidth, rawHeight);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
UInt8 *rawImage = (UInt8 *)malloc(rawHeight * rawWidth * rawBytesPerPixel);
CGContextRef rawContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImage,
                                                rawWidth,
                                                rawHeight,
                                                rawBitsPerComponent,
                                                rawBytesPerRow,
                                                colorSpace,
                                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// At this point, rawContext is ready for drawing, everything drawn will be in rawImage's byte array.
CGContextDrawImage(rawContext, rawRect, imageRef);

// Second step, crawl the byte array and do the evil work:
for (NSInteger y = 0; y < rawHeight; ++y) {
    for (NSInteger x = 0; x < rawWidth; ++x) {
        UInt8 *address = rawImage + x * rawBytesPerPixel + y * rawBytesPerRow;
        RGBA *pixel = (RGBA *)address;
        // If it is a grey input image, it does not matter what RGB channel to use - they shall all be the same
        if (0 != pixel->red) {
            pixel->alpha = 0;
        } else {
            pixel->alpha = UINT8_MAX;
        }
        pixel->red = 0;
        pixel->green = 0;
        pixel->blue = 0;
        // I am still not sure if this is the transformation you are searching for, but it may give you the idea.
    }
}

// Third: rawContext is ready, transformation is done. Get the image out of it
CGImageRef outputImage1 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(rawContext);
UIImage *outputImage2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImage1];
CGImageRelease(outputImage1);
```

Okay... the output is RGBA, but you can create a greyscale + alpha context and just blit your image there for conversion.

Comment: I've already tried something similar, but I end up with a `nil` value in `rawContext`. But I did not try the `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` flag. Will try it asap.

Comment: As I said, "Maybe you have to do RGBA instead due to iOS limitations.", not all values defined are possible there, Greyscale + Alpha sounds kind of exotic.

Comment: Just tried this code, and with some modifications it works. The only problem is that the image is doubled in size. Any ideas?

Comment: Without looking at your modifications it is a bit hard to tell what might be wrong. Stupid errors first: are you accidentally loading the retina image instead of the normal one? Are you a 100% sure, input and output image size differ? And if so: what size matches rawRect?

Comment: The modifications where only in the part where you set the bits value. I just put rgb to zero leaving alpha unchanged. Didn't touch everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code helped me applying hue on non-transparent area of an image.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImageView*)source colorValue:(CGFloat)hue {
    CGSize imageSize = [source.image size];
    CGRect imageExtent = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

    // Create a context containing the image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [source.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    // Setup a clip region using the image
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, source.bounds, source.image.CGImage);

    self.imageColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:1.0];
    [self.imageColor set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, source.bounds);

    // Draw the hue on top of the image.
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
    [self.imageColor set];

    UIBezierPath *imagePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageExtent];
    [imagePath fill];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context); // remove clip region

    // Retrieve the new image.
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```